Continuous dependence of solution to Laplace equation up to derivatives
Let $U \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded domain. Consider the Dirichlet boundary value
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{lcl}
         -\Delta u =f & \mbox{in}
         & U \\ 
         u = g & \mbox{on} & \partial U.
                \end{array}\right.$$
Assume $f$ can be continuously extended to $\partial U$ (i.e it is uniformly continuous).
a) Show that the solution $u$ has continuous dependence in $C(\overline{U})$ on the boundary data $g \in C(\partial U)$ and the source term $f \in C(\overline{U}).$ Assume that a solution $u$ always exists. Namely, show that if $g_n \rightarrow g$ in $C(\partial U)$ and $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $C(\overline{U})$ that the solution $u_n \rightarrow u$ in $C(\overline{U}).$
b) Show that the solution has continuous dependence in $C^k(\overline{U})$ on the boundary data $g \in C^k(\partial U)$ and the source term $f \in C^k(\overline{U})$ for any $k \geq 1$ (again assume $f$ and its first $k$ derivatives can be continuously extended to $\overline{U}$).
I am done with a by using Maximum principle but I don't have the ideas for b). Could you please give me any approaches? I really appreciate for your help. May we use induction or Green's function here?
